# In which class does this method belong?

Tags: php, oop

I'm rather new to OOP and have a general question.

Imagine I have two classes: `AddressBook` and `Contact`. An address book contains 0-n contacts.

**Where would you put the method `getAllContactsFromAddressBook()`?**

```
class AddressBook {
    private $addressBookId;

    function __construct($addressBookId) {
         $this->addressBookId = $addressBookId;
    }

    // HERE?
    // getAllContactsFromAddressBook() { ... }
}
```

and

```
class Contact {
    private $contactId;

    function __construct($contactId) {
         $this->contactId = $contactId;
    }

    function getContactDetails($contactId) { ... }

    // OR BETTER HERE?
    // getAllContactsFromAddressBook($addressBookId) { ... }
}
```

What is the best practice in such situations? Thank you for your explanations!

Comment: It's obvious that you would NOT want to put it in the Contact class. Logically, it would not make sense to get all of the contacts from a contact. Instead, you want to get all contacts from something that holds all of the contacts, which in this case is an address book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would put inside class `AddressBook` the method `getAllContacts`.

Just try do read how the function call would look like

```
$addressBook = new AddressBook();
$addressBook->getAllContacts();
```

The contacts belong to the address book, so you ask to the address book to give you his contacts.

Answer (score 4):

I like to think of it in terms of real life objects.

If I want all the contacts in my address book, I will *go to the Address Book* and get the contacts from it. I would not go to a Contact and say "what contacts are in the same address book as you?"

Additionally, a Contact may be in more than one Address Book. It makes more sense to ask the Address Book in every way.

Therefore, it should be a `public function` of the `AddressBook`.